# Semantic UI modal closes on Twitter Typeahead selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, semantic-ui, twitter-typeahead

I have a [Twitter Typeahead](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) inside of a [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/) [modal](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html). The desired behavior is that the user can select something from the typeahead and still work within the modal before confirming their selection. However, if the user clicks on a selection, then the modal closes early. This only occurs when clicking; if the user uses the arrow keys to select an option, or uses <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete, then the modal stays open as desired.

I've made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAL9y/3/) to demonstrate the problem. Minimal code summary below:

### index.html:

```
<div id="pick-user-modal" class="ui modal"><i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">Select user</div>
    <div class="content">
      <input type="text" id="user-field" />
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <a id="send-request" class="ui green button">Select user</a>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="green ui button" id="show-pick-user-modal">Select user</a>
```

### main.js:

```
$('#pick-user-modal').modal();
$('#show-pick-user-modal').click(function () {
    $('#pick-user-modal').modal('show');
});
var $users = $('#user-field');
$users.typeahead({
    name: 'users',
    local: ["Andy","Betty","Charles","Dotty","Elton","Fred","Grace","Harriet",
            "Ichabod","Jenny","Karen","Louise","Michael","Nathan","Oswald",
            "Patricia","Quendy","Robert","Sylvia","Thomas","Ursula","Vivian",
            "Wendy","Xavier","Yvonne","Zachary"]
});
function setUser(e,d){
    alert(d.value);
}
$users.on('typeahead:selected',setUser);
$users.on('typeahead:autocompleted',setUser);
```

I've tried returning `false` from `setUser` and also calling `e.preventDefault()`, but neither has solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen exactly the same issue. The only thing that stops it from closing is setting closeable to false,
which is not a setting I would otherwise use.

When you enable debug mode for the modal, you get the following message:

[image: 1]

I suspect that jquery isn't aware of the element.